# Typescript type level filtering

Tags: typescript

I need to filter a Map type from union

```
type B = FilterMap<string | { a: 1 }> // { a: 1 }
type C = FilterMap<boolean | { b:2 }> // { b:2 }
type D = FilterMap<number | { c: 3 }> // { c: 3 }
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the predefined type [`Extract<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union), to extract any object type from a union:

```
type FilterMap<T> = Extract<T, object>
type B = FilterMap<string | { a: 1 }> // { a: 1 }
type C = FilterMap<boolean | { b:2 }> // { b:2 }
type D = FilterMap<number | { c: 3 }> // { c: 3 }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgWQIZgDwBUB8UAvFAKIAewKGAxsHgDRQD2ARgFYR34BQokUAELFYiZOizYAzlTgA7AOZQAPlADeUDAC4oARigBfQgHpj6zTv0G+4aAGER8JKkw5WzZgggY5K86y0AJkMTMw0A4Ot+aAARRzEXSTkAVwBbVlQ-DRodAGYQqFNzHKh8gyA)